# How to minimize sorting runtime complexity?

Tags: c#, .net-core

i wrote an application which is a custom console that allows execution of various commands. One of the commands allows sorting an array of integers. The input data is a string, which is a list of comma separated numbers.

**My question is - how to minimize the sorting code runtime complexity as much as possible?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CustomConsole.Common;
namespace Shell_Commander.Commands
{
class SortCommand : ICommand
{

    private string _sortCommandName = "sort";
    public string Name { get { return this._sortCommandName; } set { _sortCommandName = value; } }


    public string Execute(string parameters)
    {
        var splittedParameters = parameters.Split(",",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var arr = new List<int>();

        int number;
        int parameterIndex = 0;

        foreach (var item in splittedParameters)
        {
            parameterIndex++;

            if (int.TryParse(item, out number))
            {
                arr.Add(number);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The {parameterIndex}'st parameter isn't a number. Value: '{item}'.");
            }
        }

        int temp = 0;

        for (int write = 0; write < arr.Count; write++)
        {
            for (int sort = 0; sort < arr.Count - 1; sort++)
            {
                if (arr[sort] > arr[sort + 1])
                {
                    temp = arr[sort + 1];
                    arr[sort + 1] = arr[sort];
                    arr[sort] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        var result = "";

        Console.Write("The sort result is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            result += arr[i] + " ";
            Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Example - for the '4,1,2' input, the output will be:

```
"The sort result is: 1 2 4".
```

Comment: Are you talking about the little swap sort routine that you have in the code?

Comment: Use efficient sorting algorithm, like QuickSort? Use sorting from standard library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just replace your little sorting routine with calling the [Sort method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8) on array variable.

```
arr.Sort();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). In fact, you can simply use [LINQ's OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) method, which is internally using [QuickSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

So, here's the solution, instead of double `for`, use this:

```
var sortedArray = arr.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why not just `Array.Sort`?

Comment: @dyukha it's up to you, choose any of the already existing in C# sort functions.